# What does this exception mean when running LibSVM using Weka?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, svm

I am writing this code to do a 5-fold cross validation using LibSVM using Weka.

```
    LibSVM svm = new LibSVM();
    svm.setKernelType(new SelectedTag(2, LibSVM.TAGS_KERNELTYPE));
    svm.setDegree(2);
    //Run a cross validation to select the right parameters
    CVParameterSelection ps = new CVParameterSelection();
    ps.setClassifier(svm);
    ps.setNumFolds(5);  // using 5-fold CV
    ps.addCVParameter("G 1 10 .1");

    // build and output best options
    //I get exception below ->>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    ps.buildClassifier(isTrainingSet);
    System.out.println(Utils.joinOptions(ps.getBestClassifierOptions()));
```

But it throws an exception saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Error: gamma < 0
at weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM.buildClassifier(LibSVM.java:1690)
at weka.classifiers.meta.CVParameterSelection.findParamsByCrossValidation(CVParameterSelection.java:377)
at weka.classifiers.meta.CVParameterSelection.findParamsByCrossValidation(CVParameterSelection.java:354)
at weka.classifiers.meta.CVParameterSelection.buildClassifier(CVParameterSelection.java:628)
at ExtractTopics.main(ExtractTopics.java:164)
```

I think the parameter gamme never is less than zero, right? the initial value is 1 and final value is 10 with 10 steps. So, why is this exception then?

Comment: Answered my own question below.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question below.

The last parameter among the three values is not the amount of step size to take. It is the number of steps to perform. So it was incorrect to say above that I want to perform 0.1 steps. It should have been 100 steps so that Weka can infer that it needs to take 0.1 step size internally.

Using [1 10 100] helped and it ran fine.

The answer I found is here - http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Problem-evaluating-classifier-C-lt-0-error-td31971.html